# Rails CSV Upload Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm using [active_admin_import](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_import) to import CSV files into active_admin. When uploading the file, I keep getting a "CSV::MalformedCSVError" that states I have an Unclosed quoted field on line xx.

I checked that line, and every line around that line and there are no empty quotes anywhere near it. When I try deleting that line, the error then changes to "Unclosed quoted field on lie 415, and so on.

[image: Error]

Here is what my active_admin_import code looks like:

```
active_admin_import validate: false,
   on_duplicate_key_update: [:description, :price, :notes],
   ignore: [:name, :created_at, :updated_at]
```

Comment: try to check your CSV file which you going to import this error occur because of format change

Comment: @uzaif I checked over the CSV file over and over and over, I even deleted the lines that were throwing the errors. Wouldn't it upload the cell data as double-quoted strings? I tried removing instances of single quotes (such as linens'n things) and also tried escaping quotes ( \' ) with no luck

Comment: try any online CSV file Checker so it will tell you where is problem http://csvlint.io

Comment: I just ran it through the linter and it showed zero errors

Comment: Check the file encoding. If it's encoded in US-ASCII encoding it might throw this error. If that's the case you can open it up in a text editor and re-save it with the correct encoding. This sometimes happens when exporting a CSV file from Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this, I realized upon converting my CSV to JSON I had a lot of "\r\n" (carriage return and line feed) showing up in my strings that wouldn't display in a CSV file. I got rid of them simply by running

```
mystr.gsub(/\r\n/," "))
```

and it removed these errors.